Filtering hexagons using sf
I stumbled across this answer because I want to create a fine hexagon grid. The answer works; however, R freezes when I try to filter a large amount of hexagons (smaller ones) using the provided code
hexgrid_UK <- hexgrid[c(unlist(st_contains(UK, hexgrid)), 
                    unlist(st_overlaps(UK, hexgrid))) ,]

Is there a more efficient way to filter the hexagons that are located within the polygon?

Is using [tag:h3] an option?

Could you clarify a bit by saying how many is a large amount?

That method looks really bad because its doing two predicate tests, st_contains to get each hex fully inside the UK, and then st_overlaps to get the hexes that intersect the boundary. That seems wasteful. How long does it take (using the scale="medium" UK boundary and not the "large" one which is overcomplicated for this test)?
system.time(
hexgrid[c(unlist(st_contains(UK, hexgrid)), 
          unlist(st_overlaps(UK, hexgrid))) ,]
)

   user  system elapsed 
  1.256   0.000   1.256 

Instead, lets try st_intersects which should catch both sets of hexes in one go:
system.time(
hexgrid_UK_2 <- hexgrid[c(unlist(st_intersects(UK, hexgrid))) ,] 
)

   user  system elapsed 
   0.03    0.00    0.03 

Much faster. But is it the same? I set an ID column on hexgrid so I could test this:
> setdiff(hexgrid_UK_2$ID, hexgrid_UK_1$ID)
[1] 15

The 15th hex in hexgrid is included in the faster code, plotting it shows it to be just barely touching the UK polygon, so I think it shares a point with the border which is enough to satisfy st_intersects but not st_overlaps. Does that matter to you? I usually crop my hexgrids to my polygon so I don't get a hexagonal coastline, which means this difference doesn't matter.
Another possible way is to look for zero-distance between the hexes and the polygon, but this is slower than st_intersects (but faster than the original):
system.time(
hexgrid_UK_3 <- hexgrid[as.numeric(st_distance(hexgrid, UK)[,1]) == 0,]
)
  user  system elapsed 
 0.109   0.000   0.109 

This returns the same as method 2 with one extra hex compared to the original method 1.
So, I'd say use method 2, st_intersects.
I've another idea which is to partition the hexes so that simple point tests of the centroids means you are only doing full polygonal geometry tests on a subset. So for example, any hexes with a centroid in the polygon are included because they are clearly inside the polygon, and any hexes with a centroid further than the radius of the hexes from the polygon are not included because they cannot be in or over the polygon. Those two tests can be done using point-polygon geometry only. This leaves a few hexes to test with complex polygon-polygon geometry tests. If I get this working I'll update and let you know if its faster, but its precise timing will depend on the geometry of the polygon and how it relates to the hexes.

Thank you, this works great. I am working with more than one million hexagons and st_intersects does the job. It was impossible with the code that I had before.

Do you have some latitude in choosing your grid (apart from it being fine)?
The reason I am asking is that I have good experience in utilizing H3 / via the {h3jsr} package.
It seems to thrive on the use case of "hexagonal grid covering area of interest".
For an example of it in action consider the following piece of code. It is rather fast, but you are limited in hexagon size to one of the the presets recognized by H3 (I believe there are 12).
library(sf)

# area of interest
aoi <- c("UK")

# area of interest as a  polygon
aoi_countries <- giscoR::gisco_get_countries(country = aoi, resolution = "03")

# list or H3 cells covering area of interest; resolution is important
raw_cell_list <- h3jsr::polygon_to_cells(aoi_countries, res = 5, simple = FALSE)$h3_addresses[[1]]

# cells as centroids
cells_sf_point <- h3jsr::cell_to_point(raw_cell_list) |>
   st_as_sf()

# cells as polygons
cells_sf_poly <- h3jsr::cell_to_polygon(raw_cell_list) |> 
   st_as_sf()

# report results
plot(st_geometry(aoi_countries))
plot(cells_sf_point, pch = 4, col = "gray", cex = 1/2, add = T)
plot(cells_sf_poly, pch = 4, border = "red", add = T)



I think h3 is a great idea for global mapping since you don't get any grid distortion at the poles. But on a UK scale where you could safely work in projected coordinates, I prefer to create a regular hexagonal grid - not least because they'll all have the same area in your projection and you have no chance of one of the H3 pentagons popping up...
